# How do I get string output of compiled C# code?

Tags: c#

I'm using **CSharpCodeProvider** class to compile c# code.

for example the code is,

```
using System;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bar.SayHello();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to get the final string output after execution, in this case "Hello World".
The object of **CompilerResults** which is returned has an output field but it online shows messages about compilation process. The output file with .exe extension is also created just fine and It shows that string.

I'm looking for either a way to extract that string from exe file generated, or any other way.

**EDIT:**
Is there a way to get the output string WITHOUT running that process and extracting it from there?

Comment: This may or may not be the same question, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648290/interacting-with-assembly-generated-by-csharpcodeprovider

Comment: Do you want to extract data from the generated program file, or do you want to *run* the program and get the output?

Comment: You say you have the `.exe` generated correctly. Is "Run the exe using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) and redirect standard output" a suitable answer? If so, I'll post the code :)

Comment: @RB. Yes all I need is the string. Anyway possible.

Comment: You could write the output to a file?

Comment: @Guffa I want the string output. That "Hello World", anyway.

Comment: @JensKloster How exactly do I get the output is my question, what I'll do with it is unrelated :)

Comment: @MudasirSoomro Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic for how to redirect the standard output (you shouldn't need to redirect standard error or standard input for your purposes)

Comment: @MudasirSoomro It is an unsual request - therefore I thinkt your context is relevant. Maybe there is a smarter way to achieve your goal :)

Comment: Do you even need to compile the code? Does the code differ much, or would it be possible to get the string from the source code?

Comment: @Guffa You don't get the problem. See, using socket programming I'm making a server that connects to different clients. The clients can send in their code that requires them to output a string. After receiving the code, I compile the code, (And yes it WILL differ, in fact there will be test cases to test the string output) get the string and send acknowledgement after checking it.

Comment: @RB. Thank you. It works, although the program is stuck if the code contains "Console.ReadLine". I have to either close the console window explicitly in order to continue or I have to send StandardInput everytime Console.ReadLine occurs.

Comment: @MudasirSoomro: Of course I didn't get the problem, you hadn't explained it. :)